# How do I wait for a promise's "then" block to execute within nested forEach loops before the loops iterate again?

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I have 3 total forEach loops and I want the first two to wait on a promise's then block to execute before they start over and iterate again. I've demonstrated this with console.log statements labeled 1, 2, and 3.

I want the console logs to go in order, like "1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 etc" 
Instead what I'm getting is "1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3"
How do I make all of this sequential?
fetchCandidatesByCity is the mongoose find method, which returns a promise.

```
axios.get(FEED_URL).then(data => {
let candidatesWithMessageSent = [];

data.data.jobs.forEach(job => {
  console.log("1");
  // console.log(candidatesWithMessageSent);
  job.city.forEach(cityAndState => {
    console.log("2");

    let jobState = extractState(cityAndState);

    let jobLocation = addSpaceAfterComma(cityAndState.toLowerCase());

    let jobCity = extractCity(jobLocation);


    fetchCandidatesByCity(jobCity)
      .then(candidates => {
        candidates.forEach((candidate, index) => {
          console.log("3");
          const candidateId = candidate._id.toString();

          if (index <= MAX_MESSAGE_LIMIT &&
            !containsUberLyft(job.title) &&
            priceIsHigh(job.price) &&
            !candidateHasMessage(candidatesWithMessageSent, candidateId)) {

            const jobURL = `http://www.jobs2careers.com/click.php?id=${job.id}.${PUBLISHER_ID}`;

            // candidate has received a job notification, so add candidate to candidatesWithMessageSent

            candidatesWithMessageSent = [ ...candidatesWithMessageSent, candidateId ];

          }
          return;
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
});
```

});

Comment: Your sample code never uses `data` and `pieceOfData`. Does this represent the actual scenario you are asking about, or would you actually use them? If the latter, you need to show how they would be used.

Comment: The function itself is long, but I can show it. This sample code is an abbreviated version.

Comment: What you want to do with the results of all the async operations is an important part of determining what solution works best so we need more detail on your loop and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I updated my code to include the actual scenario in which I'm using these forEach loops. When I log candidatesWithMessageSent just inside the first forEach loop, it is always empty, whereas it should be populated since I add candidateId to it within fetchCandidatesByCity

Comment: please dont keep on change your question. I answered this question hour ago (ask by you but in another post), by the time I post my answer, you delete the question. Now you open another question, and I answer again based on your question, after I answer, you change your question back to previous post. stop doing it

Answer (score 7):

A common design pattern to iterate an array serially using async operations is using `.reduce()` where you accumulate a promise.  In outline, it works like this:

```
array.reduce(function(p, item) {
    return p.then(function() {
        return someAsyncPromise(item);
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function(finalValue) {
    // all done here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

`Promise.resolve()` is passed in as the initial value of the accumulator.  Each iteration of the loop, then does `return p.then(someOperation)`.

This essentially chains a whole bunch of operations together like this:

```
Promise.resolve().then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...)
```

Where each time your custom function is called by a `.then()` handler, it is passed the next iteration value of the array and returns a promise that will be waited on before the next time `f` is called.

---

Since you have two nested array iteration loops, you can nest one inside the other like this:

```
myData.reduce(function(p, nestedArray) {
    return p.then(function() {
        return nestedArray.reduce(function(p2, item) {
            return p2.then(function() {
                return someAsyncPromise(item);
            });
        }, Promise.resolve());
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function(finalVal) {
    // all done here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Or, if you aren't using the promise resolved result of the prior iteration from the outer `reduce()`, you can simplify that a bit like this:

```
myData.reduce(function(p, nestedArray) {
    return nestedArray.reduce(function(p2, item) {
        return p2.then(function() {
            return someAsyncPromise(item);
        });
    }, p);
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function(finalVal) {
    // all done here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

---

This is a place where the [Bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) makes things easier because you can use `Promise.mapSeries()` to iterate an array in series and accumulate an array of results:

```
 Promise.mapSeries(myData, function(nestedArray) {
     return Promise.mapSeries(nestedArray, function(item) {
         return someAsyncPromise(item);
     });
 }).then(function(results) {
    // all done here
 }).catch(function(err) {
     // error here
 });
```

---

In all these scenarios, you can either accumulate the final result in one object that becomes the resolved value of the final promise or you can use it for side effects where you have some other object defined in a higher scope that you are modifying and you then use that object when you're all done.

Comment: if you're nesting these things and the inner array does not depend on previous results, you might simplify the inner `return p.then(function() { return nestedArray.reduce(…, Promise.resolve()); })` to `return nestedArray.reduce(…, p);`

Comment: @Bergi - I added that as an option.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let seq = Promise.resolve()
let myData = [[1.1,1.2],[2.1,2.2]];
function findUser () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(['a','b']);
        }, 500);
    });
}
myData.forEach(data => {
    seq = seq.then(() => { // chain myData.forEach
        console.log(data);
        let seq = Promise.resolve();
        data.forEach(data => {
            seq = seq.then(() => { // chain data.forEach
                console.log(data);
                return findUser({}).then(users => {
                    users.forEach(user => {
                        console.log(data, user);
                    })
                })
            })
        })
        return seq;
    });
});
```